# Corona SDK - change a variable for the duration of a drag event

Tags: coronasdk

I have a "seed" object which has an instance method `seed:fall()` which is called by my `update` function (which runs every frame).  I've got a "touch" event listener on it so the user can drag it around.  When it's being dragged, however, it's still trying to fall, which makes the drag interaction glitchy.

I've added an instance variable to my seed "class" called `seed.falling`.  The fall() function now checks that `seed.falling` is true before moving the seed down the screen.  The next step is to set seed.falling to false when the drag starts, and then set it back to true when the drag stops.  I can't figure out this last part though.

Any ideas anyone?  Is there a "stop dragging" event i could set a listener for, to switch `seed.falling` back on?  Is there a nicer way of achieving what i want?

Comment: Are you using the "touch" event phases: "began", "moved" and "ended"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0,1)
local dd = display.newRect(400,100,200,200)
physics.addBody(dd,"dynamic")
dd:addEventListener("touch", function(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        dd.bodyType = "static"
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        dd.x,dd.y = event.x,event.y
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        dd.bodyType = "dynamic"
    end
end)
```

I think this case is what you want?

Comment: I don't have physics on the object but i did use the event.phase attribute to handle the situation - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, here's how i solved this.

Basically i have an attribute "seed.falling" which the seed:fall method checks before moving the seed.  And i set that attribute to false if we're *not* at the "ended" phase of the drag event, which stops the seed falling.

```
function Seed:new(x,y)
  print("Seed:new, x = " .. (x or nil) .. ", y = " .. (y or nil) )
  local seed = display.newImage("seed_icon.png")
  seed.x =    x
  seed.y =    y
  seed.name = 'seed'   
  seed.falling = true

  function seed:fall()
    if(self.falling) then
      self.y = self.y + 1
    end
  end

  function seed:drag(event)
    seed.x = event.x
    seed.y = event.y
    if(event.phase == "ended") then
      seed.falling = true
    else 
      seed.falling = false
    end
  end    

  seed:addEventListener("touch", drag)

  return seed
end      

function drag(event)
  seed = event.target
  seed:drag(event)
end
```

It's not a very good solution i think as it leaves the seed stranded on the screen sometimes - possibly when you drag a seed over another falling seed.